# Generate Python Class and SQLAlchemy code from XSD to store XML on Postgres

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, xsd, sqlalchemy

I have some very complex XSD schemas to work with. By complex I mean that each of these XSD would correspont to about 20 classes / tables in a database, with each table having approximately 40 fields. And I have 18 different XSD like that to program.

What I'm trying to achieve is: Get a XML file defined by the XSD and save all the data in a PostgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy. Basically I need a CRUD application that will persist a XML file in the database following the model of the XSD schema, and also be able to retrieve an object from the database and create a XML file.

I want to avoid having to manually create the python classes, the sqlalchemy table definitions, the CRUD code. This would be a monumental job, subject to a lot of small mistakes, given the complexity of the XSD files.

I can generate python classes from XSD in many ways like GenerateDS, PyXB, etc... I need to save those objects in the database. I'm open to any suggestions, even if the suggestion is conceptually different that what I'm describing.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use generateDS to create django models from your XSD.  You do this using the gends_run_gen_django script, which is located under the django directory in the generateDS source.  Here is some [documentation](http://www.rexx.com/~dkuhlman/generateDS.html#django-generating-models-and-forms) on that functionality.  Relevant quote:

> Here is an overview of the process:
>
> ```
> Step 1. Generate bindings -- Run generateDS.py.
> Step 2. Extract simpleType definitions from schema -- Run
> gends_extract_simple_types.py.
> Step 3. Generate models.py and forms.py -- Run gends_generate_django.py.
> ```
>
> The script gends_run_gen_django.py performs these three steps.

I believe django should give you most of the functionality of sqlalchemy.  However, if you decide to use sqlalchemy instead then generateDS' django functionality might be a good model on which to base a similar sqlalchemy solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a way directly, but you could indirectly go from XSD to a SQL Server DB, and then import the DB from SQLAlchemy