# How to generate models.py classes by xsd in django?

Tags: python, django, model, xsd

So, i am trying to generate models.py classes with django. I'm trying to do it with gends_run_gen_django.py. I watched this at this question : [Generate Python Class and SQLAlchemy code from XSD to store XML on Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750340/generate-python-class-and-sqlalchemy-code-from-xsd-to-store-xml-on-postgres/17751784)

I'm trying this command.

```
gends_run_gen_django.py -f -p C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\generateDS.py  C:\Users\test\Documents\Files\XMLSchemaPersonAdress.xsd
```

But i getting this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\gends_run_gen_django.py", 
   line 201, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\gends_run_gen_django.py", line 195, in main
    generate(options, schema_name)
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\gends_run_gen_django.py", line 91, in generate
    if not run_cmd(options, args):
  File "C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\gends_run_gen_django.py", line 118, in run_cmd
    process = Popen(args, stderr=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
  File "c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\users\test\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

What i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

So i contacted Dave Kuhlman and we could answer this question:
https://bitbucket.org/dkuhlman/generateds/issues/18/cant-use-gends_run_gen_djangopy